# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Button no longer works when website is published

Tags: asp.net, button

I have created a website in Visual Studio 2015, it has an ASP.NET button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Large" style="height: 31px; width: 168px; z-index: 1; left: 28px; top: 356px; position: absolute;" Text="Find Practice(s)" />
```

This button works as it should when I test the site in Chrome, IE11 and Microsoft Edge.  When I publish the site to the server on GoDaddy this button no longer works.  You can click it all day long and the results I get during testing no longer occur.  You can actually see the site at www.cpmhlocate.com.  The site is simple enough type in an address, click the button and you then go to a page containing a Google Map with markers and then the nearest offices within 30 miles are displayed.  When testing this is exactly what happens, but yet after the site is published, this button no longer works as it should....

Comment: What more information could I provide?  BUTTON...Works when testing it in Visual Studio 2015....does NOT WORK after publishing the site to GoDaddy.  And believe me I have been Googling this all morning, hell I even Binged it and found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment, so I'll leave this here. On inspecting your button's action, I see this error message:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: There was an error with >Google's Geocoding Service: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Looks like a showstopper to me.